# Laravel 5.3 Route::get() returns error Class [classname] does not exist

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel, and it's my first time creating a controller. I've also searched for hours for similar problems, but could not find any solution that will work for me.

When I was not using a controller yet, I was able to display a page using this code inside **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**:

```
    Route::get('/', function(){
        if(View::exists('pages.index'))
            return view('pages.index');
        else
            return view('errors.404',['xp'=>'pages/index']);
    });
```

The problem started when I created a controller and substituted the above block of code into this:

```
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
```

After using the above code, I got this error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: Class SiteController does not exist

Here are my complete codes:

inside **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    public function boot(){
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function map(){
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes(){
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });

        /*site view*/
        Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    }
    protected function mapApiRoutes(){
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
        });
    }
}
```

inside **app/Http/Controllers/SiteController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SiteController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->check_page(['pages.index']);
    }

    public function check_page($page){
        $xp = str_replace('.','/',$page);
        if(View::exists($page))
            return view($page);
        else
            return view('errors.404',$xp);
    }
}
```

And maybe I'm just plain dumb (fine), but I can't find anything from this "Greek" [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers) which would help me at all.

I hope someone out there has encountered this before and could share their solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Put `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');` inside routes/web.php and see?

Comment: have you done the entry for route in routes/web.php?

Comment: I just did that, and also added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; on top of my SiteController.php. But now I got a new error:

ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 71:
Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed that by removing the brackets from $this->check_page(['pages.index']);... but now it's displaying a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first run the command `composer dump-autoload`

If its not work, than follow those steps:

step-1: create route inside `routes\web.php`
    `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');`

step-2: create a controller using `cmd` like `php artisan make:controller SiteController`

inside: **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php** should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api'],
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
        });
    }
}
```

Inside: **app/Http/Controllers/SiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('pages.index');
    }
}
```

Create view page inside the:
`resources/views/pages/index.blade.php`

Run server using cmd `php artisan serve`

Hope this help's you!

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` did not do anything, but following your instructions helped me figure out the root of the error. In my **SiteController->index**, I changed the line `$this->check_page(['pages.index']);` into `return $this->check_page(['pages.index']);`. The missing `return` word solved everything. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: **Side Note:** `php artisan serve` gives me **[ErrorException]
  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)**. It's not really a big deal, for now, but if you have any idea why I'm getting this, that would also be much appreciated.

Comment: @FlameDenise you must be run the command inside your project dir folder For example: your project dir is: `c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5.3` inside `laravel5.3` folder you run the cmd: `php artisan serve`

Comment: Solved this now! I changed my directory previously in order to remove "public" from my URL. I ran the command in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\project and it worked. Thanks for your help.